# NSDateFormatter returns nil

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to parse a date passed in the format:

```
"2014-03-26T05:07:42.14286Z"
```

My `NSDateFormatter` code looks like this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'SS'Z'"];
self.createdAt = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@""2014-03-26T05:07:42.14286Z""];
```

But it just returns `nil`. I've tried multiple variations with and without the ticks but I seem to be missing something. Am I using `NSDateFormatter` incorrectly, misunderstanding the usage of ticks or something else entirely?

Comment: Put a local, and your format do not manage "`.14286`" of your example.

Comment: @Larme You mean locale, and why? It will default to the current locale which is fine in this case.

Comment: Do not quote the `Z` in the format string. It's the timezone and you want it parsed, not treated as a literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formatter returns nil if the given string doesn't correspond to the expected format. Your format string was almost right, you just needed to :

- Apostrophe should only be used for literals
- Milliseconds should be specified as 'SSS' and match the separation (use ss.SSS)

The correct format string is :

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSDate *d = [df dateFromString:@"2014-03-26T05:07:42.14286Z"];
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you've just changed the variable name (but not done so consistently) and removed the quoting from the `-` and `:`, both of which are fine to be quoted. Is there anything else I've missed? Have you tested this?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i corrected the answer. I just tested it, it works

Comment: Right - that's better, but it would be better still if you gave explanatory text, rather than just a block of code. I assume the problem is really just that the OP's format didn't include anything about fractional seconds. (I think it would be worth setting the time zone to UTC, as an aside... given that we're matching Z as a literal.)

Comment: The `Z` should NOT be in quotes and the number of `S` should match the number of fractional second digits in the string.

Comment: No problem i added the explanation on how to provide the right date format

Comment: Works like a charm thanks for the explanation. Oddly, the `NSDate` object this creates does not seem to differ when the "Z" is quoted or unquoted. Is this just because my date string happens to be in GMT?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the below line to modified line

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'SS'Z'"];
```

Modified line:-

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```